# Using Codeigniter 2 with Doctrine ORM 2 < PHP v5.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine

Sorry for my bad English..

I read that the use of Codeigniter 2 with Doctrine 2 works only in PHP version => 5.3 because of namespaces.

Is there a possibility to operate at a lower version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Doctrine2 has a minimum requirement of PHP 5.3. Porting it to PHP 5.2 would be insane. Also, PHP 5.3 is the only currently supported version of PHP, so I would highly suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not upgrade because this is shared web hosting service. One solution is that I setup CI2 and Doctrine2 on localhost. Is there a possibility that I use Doctrine v1 with CI2?

Comment: That surely should be possible. But I'd personally advise moving to a host with PHP 5.3 support.

Comment: Is there any tutorial how to integrate Doctrine v1 with CI2? Thanks